# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required ... Novice programmer, appreciate any guidance

Tags: server, require-once

I'm a novice in server-side programming so any advice is appreciated.

I have some PHP files uploaded on a virtual server (000webhost.com) and I'm having trouble with locating a file I'm requiring in another PHP file. The register.php is attempting to "require_once" the update_user_info.php

Here's the code for register.php (Which I've taken from a tutorial and adjusted it with my variables):

```
<?php

define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'../update_user_info.php'); 

$db = new update_user_info();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST       ['password']) && isset($_POST['branch']) && isset($_POST['gender'])) {

// receiving the post params
$username = $_POST['username'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$branch = $_POST['branch'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];


// check if user is already existed with the same email
if ($db->CheckExistingUser($email)) {
    // user already existed
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // create a new user
    $user = $db->StoreUserInfo($username, $name, $email, $password, $branch, $gender);
    if ($user) {
        // user stored successfully
        $response["error"] = FALSE;
        $response["user"]["username"] = $user["username"];
        $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
        $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
        $response["user"]["branch"] = $user["branch"];
        $response["user"]["gender"] = $user["gender"];

        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE; 
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
 }
} else {
$response["error"] = TRUE;
$response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter (username, name, email or password) is missing!";
echo json_encode($response);
 }
?>
```

And here's a screenshot of the error that's occurring when attempting to visit the link containing the register.php:

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghTip.png)

What I've tried so far:

1- tried to use `require_once __DIR__."/../filename.php";` and lots more of the same, basically tinkering the statement with different language constructs and constants.

2-Read tutorials on the correct way to use require once but their cases is almost always very different. Either they are using WAMP/XAMPP -meaning they have a local path not a virtual one- So no luck there.

3- tried to change .htaccess file, as someone said in a post that it solved his problem.

4- I'm certain that both files are uploaded to the same directory. Yet it says "No such file".

Does anyone have an idea of where the error could be stemming from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I'm certain that both files are uploaded to the same directory." If both are in the same directory, why do you go two directories up?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `require_once(__DIR__.'/update_user_info.php');`

Comment: I've tried to put
 require_once(__ROOT__.'/public_html/ConnectDB/update_user_info.php');

It still doesn't work..

Comment: `__ROOT__` is the parent directory of your php file, not the directory the file is in.

Comment: I see. So what should the path be after (require_once) for these uploaded files? Thanks for answering my questions BTW.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem and it wasn't path-related. Thank you very much for your time.=)